# I need to drop duplicates from a DF based on two columns & return the row w/ min & max based on 3rd column

Tags: pandas

I have a python dataframe with many values that looks like this:

```
Date       Size     Price
4/17/2019   3         71.00
4/17/2019   3         70.12
4/17/2019   3         69.00
4/17/2019   3         71.55
4/17/2019   50        73.45
4/17/2019   50        72.45
4/17/2019   50        71.45
4/17/2019   50        70.45
```

I need to drop duplicated date and time and return the min and max rows from column 'Price'--the desired result is:

```
Date       Size     Price
4/17/2019   3         69.00
4/17/2019   3         71.55
4/17/2019   50        73.45
4/17/2019   50        70.45
```

I've tried to use drop duplicates and groupby(), but haven't seemed to come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = ['Date' ,'Size', 'Price']
l2 = [['4/17/2019', 3 ,71.00],
      ['4/17/2019', 3, 70.12],
      ['4/17/2019' ,3, 69.00],
      ['4/17/2019', 3, 71.55],
      ['4/17/2019', 50, 73.45],
      ['4/17/2019', 50, 72.45],
      ['4/17/2019', 50, 71.45],
      ['4/17/2019', 50, 70.45],
      ['4/18/2019', 50, 70.45]]

df = pd.DataFrame(l2, columns =l1)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  #making sure its dtype is date

## sort based on price, then group it based on Date then aggregate the min and max values
sorted_grouped_agg = df.sort_values(by=['Price']).groupby('Date').agg(['min','max'])

print(sorted_grouped_agg)


#######   Output  #######

              Size        Price
            min max    min    max
Date
2019-04-17    3  50  69.00  73.45
2019-04-18   50  50  70.45  70.45

#################################
```